# Full node is missing transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, full-node

I am running a full node (geth + lighthouse) on mainet for a few months. In a random test i found that my the geth client did not heard of some transactions (i took random blocks from Etherscan, and from each block some random transactions and looked for the transaction hash in the logs).

It is important to me that my node will hear about all transactions all the time.

I am trying to understand how could this happen and how to avoid this situation in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions that are mined through flashbots won't appear in the pending pool. They aren't propagated at all before they appear in a block.

Comment: Furthermore to clarify: there is no requirement for transactions to appear in the public mempool. To get better trade execution, everybody should use services like [MEV Blocker](https://mevblocker.io/), so that people do not listen to transactions and try to frontrun your trades.